# filter out TreeId if the area equals to zero in r

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I am trying to remove treeId if the area is equal to zero. When i print the treeID i can see the area been zero but how can i filter out this point. I cannot find the attribute area anywhere in the header.

```
> las_x
class        : LAS (v1.4 format 6)
memory       : 5.9 Kb 
extent       : 368538.2, 368538.3, 5807601, 5807601 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.  : WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N 
area         : 0 m²
points       : 3  points
density      : 0 points/m²
```

Answer (score 0):

It is computed on the-fly when printed. You can use `st_area()` or `area()` to get the area. Be careful: 0 m² is likely a rounded value, maybe the actual value is 0.0001 or any very small number.